# Create a single jar with multiple modules

Tags: java, maven

I was trying to create a multimodule project with maven. It works fine but its making seprate jar for every module. could you please tell me how to compile all modules together to create one jar?

I've looked through all stackoverflow posts regarding this but they are confusing me more.

Comment: Look for the Maven Assembly Plug-in or it’s successor the Maven Shade Plugin. Both can produce „fat jars“

Comment: @ChristophDahlen Maven Shade Plugin is not a successor of Maven Assembly Plugin both plugins have different tasks.

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks, didn‘t know that, actually I ever used Maven Assembly (or Spring Boot).